# (OpenGL) Uniform is preserved after context loss?

Tags: opengl, graphics

`glUniform` is needed after context loss?

in other words, uniform data is preserved although context is lost?

e.g.

```
glUseProgram(program);
glUniform1i(location, 123);
glUseProgram(0);

/* ... !! Context is lost !! ... */

glUseProgram(program);
glUniform1i(location, 123); // <- needed? uniform is preserved?
glUseProgram(0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the OpenGL context is lost, *everything* is gone. And yes, that includes program objects and their state.